# State of the art / best practice for using custom fonts on webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

the last time i was building a website was back in 2007 and using custom fonts was a pretty ugly thing. Back then the most people went with some flash applets or PHP scripts that generated images.

Well, its 2012 now and i am sure people are using other techniques now. I found a lot of different stuff online, from "Google web fonts" to "CSS3 font-face" - but i am not sure what best method is.

So tell me, what is the best way to go when using custom fonts?

Comment: Google fonts uses `@font-face`

Comment: I don't really know much about the other technologies, but I loved the simplicity of Google web fonts. It took me mere seconds to get a custom font up and running. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

"...the quality and variety of the typefaces that you’ll find on premium services like Typekit are understandably much better than what you can get for free, but if they’re just not in the budget then Google Web Fonts is absolutely your best bet ... Google Web Fonts is a completely free and super easy way to implement non-standard fonts on your website in a properly licensed and widely supported fashion."

-- from "[A Beginner’s Guide to Using Google Web Fonts" written by Joshua Johnson](http://designshack.net/articles/css/a-beginners-guide-to-using-google-web-fonts/), published 8/1/2012.